# Retornar objeto do array com condição

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

tenho um json onde preciso retornar o objeto com base em uma condição.

Eu preciso retornar o objeto correspondente ao artista selecionado pelo usuário, sendo ele selecionado pelo nome ou pelo apelido.

A busca pelo nome eu estou conseguindo fazer, mas não consigo ter sucesso para quea busca seja feita pelo apelido. Alguma sugestão de como eu faço isso?

```js
  var objeto =  [
    {
      "apelido": ["Lukas", "Vintage", "Vintage Culture"],
      "nome": "Vintage Culture",
      "title": "Cassian - Magical ft. Zolly (Vintage Culture Remix)",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxDVs4i6XJg"
},
    {
      "apelido": ["Illusionize", "Pedrinho", "Pedro"],
      "nome": "Illusionize",
      "title": "Illusionize - Down",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ea9d-FgQ-I"
},
];

var resultado = [];

function percorrer(obj) {
  for (var propriedade in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propriedade)) {
      if (typeof obj[propriedade] == "object") {
        percorrer(obj[propriedade]);
      } else {
        resultado.push(obj[propriedade]);
      }
    }
  }
}

percorrer(objeto);

var artistaSolicitado = "Lukas";

const result = objeto.find( data => data.nome === artistaSolicitado );

if (!result) {

console.log('não achou pelo apelido');

} else {

  titleArtist = result.title,
  linkVideos = result.link

} ;

console.log(result)

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
var objeto =  [
    {
      "apelido": ["Lukas", "Vintage", "Vintage Culture"],
      "nome": "Vintage Culture",
      "title": "Cassian - Magical ft. Zolly (Vintage Culture Remix)",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxDVs4i6XJg"
    },
    {
      "apelido": ["Illusionize", "Pedrinho", "Pedro"],
      "nome": "Illusionize",
      "title": "Illusionize - Down",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ea9d-FgQ-I"
    },
];
var search = window.prompt('insira nome ou apelido');
var person = objeto.find((item, idx) => item.apelido.map((item) => item.toLowerCase()).indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || item.nome.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase());

console.log(person); // caso seja "undefined" é porque não encontrou
```

Nota que a solução acima transforma as strings para *lowercase* (`.toLowerCase()`) para que a busca encontre casos como "lUkAs", mas se quiseres que a busca seja por exatamente igual ao que escreves podes alterar para:

```js
var objeto =  [
    {
      "apelido": ["Lukas", "Vintage", "Vintage Culture"],
      "nome": "Vintage Culture",
      "title": "Cassian - Magical ft. Zolly (Vintage Culture Remix)",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxDVs4i6XJg"
    },
    {
      "apelido": ["Illusionize", "Pedrinho", "Pedro"],
      "nome": "Illusionize",
      "title": "Illusionize - Down",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ea9d-FgQ-I"
    },
];
var search = window.prompt('insira nome ou apelido');
var person = objeto.find((item, idx) => item.apelido.indexOf(search) !== -1 || item.nome === search);

console.log(person); // caso seja "undefined" é porque não encontrou
```

Comment: Sensacional Miguel, sua solução funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Comment: De nada @KelvinCarvalho, ainda bem.